# How to send message to ServiceBus with the use of AmqpTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-jms, spring-amqp, spring-jmx

I need to send message to ServiceBus with custom message header properties like ContentType, Message ID, etc.

I am thinking to use Spring `AmqpTemplate` for sending message which will provide facility to set message header.

I have not found SDK for `QpidTemplate` class. I am looking for Qpid implementation of `AmqpTemplate`.

Could you please suggest how can I use `AmqpTemplate` for sending message to ServiceBus using Qpid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no QPID implementation.

Event Hubs uses AMQP 1.0 which is a very different protocol to 0.9.1, which is what the spring-amqp project is based on.

I started a PoC based on QPID protonj a couple of years ago but it's API was unstable so I abandoned it; I am told it is more stable now (but I haven't looked at it recently).

Contributions are welcome.